# Will my mostly brown lucky bamboo survive?

Tags: lucky-bamboo

I've been reading about the lucky bamboo on google, and I have one that hasn't had water for over 2 months. I was wondering whether it will survive.

I've uploaded a picture.
I think only 1 of them has a bit of green leaves.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty dead. What media was it growing in, and what do the roots look like now!

Comment: When was the last time you watered it?  Hopefully you have started watering it now in case there is still hope

Comment: Gone. Beyond recovery. :(

Comment: So, was it dead, or only mostly dead?

Answer (score 10):

- Efficient - toss it.
- Nostalgia or other emotional attachment - water it and see what
  happens.

It's mostly dead. Whether it's all dead or not would be ignored by the efficient approach, investigated by the other approach.

Don't fertilize it. Just water it. Fertilizer is not helpful to plants that are not actively growing, and would do more harm than good when reviving a near-dead but perhaps just a *tiny bit dormant* plant.

If you water it and it stays dead for another month, toss it anyway, it was all dead.

Comment: Would anything be gained by removing the brown leaves? I wondered if they're sapping potential energy from the plant's effort to survive. I don't know if that's how it works with this type of plant. Thanks!

Comment: I"d be inclined to cut the green stalk off, dip the cut end into rooting hormone and stick it in rain water to see if it roots.

Comment: @Sue those leaves are dead. They won't be sapping anything from anywhere. One could remove them for aesthetic reasons.